# ES6: Property 'selected' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, typescript, amcharts

From 'AMcharts4 codepen pre selecting areas', I want to convert the JS into ES6. However, I got error

> error TS2339: Property 'selected' does not exist on type 'Object'.

The code which I want to convert is given below:

```
// Create map instance
let chart = am4core.create("chartdivmap", am4maps.MapChart);

// Set map definition
chart.geodata = am4geodata_worldHigh;

// Set projection
chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();

// Center on the groups by default
chart.homeZoomLevel = 1.5;
chart.homeGeoPoint = {
    longitude: 10,
    latitude: 52
};

// Polygon series
let polygonSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;


var polygonTemplate = polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template;
polygonTemplate.tooltipText = "{name}";
polygonTemplate.fill = chart.colors.getIndex(0);

// Hover state
var hs = polygonTemplate.states.create("hover");
polygonTemplate.fill = am4core.color("#CCCCCC");
hs.properties.fill = am4core.color("#010101");

polygonTemplate.adapter.add("fill", function(fill, target) {
    if (target.dataItem.dataContext && target.dataItem.dataContext.selected) {
        return am4core.color("#666666");
    }
    return fill;
});
```

I tried by `let k:any = target;` and pass the variable like `function(fill, target, k)` and tried to catch the value like: `k.dataItem.dataContext.selected` which gave me more error.

Comment: Is that a compilation error or a runtime error ?

Comment: I think compilation error. ng serve is showing me the error. But if I modified the code the errors showing but the project runs anyhow and show me the expected result. My intention is to hide the error in the command line so that there will no issue during build creation.

Comment: Try with `target.dataItem.dataContext && (target.dataItem.dataContext as any).selected`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try something like this :

```
polygonTemplate.adapter.add("fill", function(fill, target) {
    const ctx = target.dataItem.dataContext as any;
    if (ctx && ctx.selected) {
        return am4core.color("#666666");
    }
    return fill;
});
```

Comment: That worked for me, but why isn't `target?.dataItem?.dataContext?.selected as any` working, is not not the same thing?